# Serialisation issue in Spring boot(able to use json serilaze)

Tags: java, json, spring, spring-boot, jackson

I am able to serialise the string field using `@JsonSerialize` applied on `POJO` getmethod, and able to see the post `serialize`  value changes in controller before binding to response, but once the controller method returns `ResponseEntity.ok(postRes)`, the serialise value is not coming in the response.
The application is `Spring Boot` `2.1.1`, `JsonSerialize` comes from  `Jackson`.
Do I need to configure anything in `Spring Boot` for this?
Usage:

```
@JsonSerialize(using = JsonString.class)
public String getInvoices() {
 return invoices;
}
```

Implementation:

```
public class JsonString extends JsonSerializer <String> {
 @Override
 public void serialize(String value, JsonGenerator gen, SerializerProvider serializers) throws IOException,
 JsonProcessingException {
  String val = value.replace("/", "");
  gen.writeString(val);
 }
}
```

Comment: Can you post the class that you are serializing as json?

Comment: @CarlitosWay
JsonSerialize(using = JsonString.class)
 public String getInvoices() {
  return invoices;
 }

JsonComponent
public class JsonString extends JsonSerializer<String> {

 Override
 public void serialize(String value, JsonGenerator gen, SerializerProvider serializers)
   throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
  
  
       String val = value.replace("/","");
  
  
  
  
  gen.writeString(val);
  

 }

}

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! You can edit your post to add code/reply to comments.

Comment: @DevSS Please, show the code from controller. Serialiser looks OK.

Comment: RequestMapping(value = "/consig", method = RequestMethod.POST)
 public ResponseEntity<ConsignmentPostResponse> consignmentsPost(){
///postRes= new ConsignmentPostResponse();

}
return ResponseEntity.ok(postRes);